# Prisma seed not being Executed

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I'm working on Nestjs project with Prisma, and I'm not able to seed to local PostgreSQL database.
seems like the seed.ts file is not being executed.
when I run `yarn prisma db seed --preview-feature` I get this `Your database has been seeded.` but the database isn't being effected.
this is what I have in seed.ts

```
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const userData: Prisma.UserCreateInput[] = [
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    email: 'alice@prisma.io',
  },
  {
    name: 'Nilu',
    email: 'nilu@prisma.io',
  },
  {
    name: 'Mahmoud',
    email: 'mahmoud@prisma.io',
  },
];

async function main() {
  console.log(`Start seeding ...`);
  for (const u of userData) {
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: u,
    });
    console.log(`Created user with id: ${user.id}`);
  }
  console.log(`Seeding finished.`);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Comment: Do any of the other console log statements print or just the final one?

Comment: Addition to what @JesseCarter mentioned, at the end of the for loop, could you try adding this ```console.log(await prisma.user.findMany({}))``` and see what gets printed?

Comment: @JesseCarter no just the final one

Comment: @TasinIshmam nothing is being logged to the console.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. In any case, that's hardly relevant because it seems to not get executed at all.  

Would you be able to create some kind of reproduction of the issue and post it online for us to check? (Failing to do this, provide other relevant information, such as folder structure, version numbers for prisma CLI, etc.). But really, a reproduction would help the most.

Comment: Furthermore, a simple workaround could be to just create a manual script in ```package.json```.  Something like the following in ```scripts``` is pretty much identical in functionality to the seed feature. ```"seed": "ts-node ./prisma/seed.ts"```

Comment: What OS are you running on Jesse?

`db seed --preview-feature` currently doesn't work on Windows. The workaround Tasin has provided will work. However, `db seed` is being re-designed.

You can follow the progress of the re-design [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8732)

Comment: @AlexRuheni I am on windows, I did what Tasin suggested And it works for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add following snipppet in your package.json.

```
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed"
  },
```

follow this -> [official guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database)